# iOS - Is there a way to generate a PDF file with layers?

Tags: ios, pdf

Quick question, that I haven't found a solid answer yet.

Is it possible to generate a PDF in iOS that includes layers, which can then be removed/separated in Photoshop?

What I'm trying to achieve is take a picture with the camera of the phone, then place text over it, submit it as pdf to a customer and then have the customer read the text and remove it.

I can do everything except the layering of the pdf and I have found some hints that this isn't possible to do with the standard iOS library, but I wanted to know if anyone has come across this before.

Thank you.

Comment: If that text you overlay is just instructional/informational text, why not use the comment functions provided by the better PDF viewers for iOS? For the customer's end, any decent PDF viewer for computers can deal with Comments, and remove them if needed.

Comment: Thanks but that won't work for what I'm trying to achieve. I need the text to be "in your face" where there's no doubt that the text is being shown, and no additional instructions are given (like open the comments section/tab)

Answer (score 0):

The standard iOS API for creating PDF files cannot create layers (optional content) in a PDF page.
This library [IFXPDFFactory](http://ipdfdev.com/ifxpdffactory-features/) seems to be able to generate PDF files with layers. 
[PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/) and [libHaru](http://libharu.org/) can also be used to generate PDF files on iOS but I do not know if they support layers.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I though but I wanted to verify it. I'm gonna leave this question open for a couple of more days to see if anyone else has a workaround for the standard library, but it seems like a third party library is the way to go on this